# Getting "At least one JPA metamodel must be present" with @WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I'm fairly new to Spring, trying to do some basic integration tests for a `@Controller`.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DemoController.class)
public class DemoControllerIntegrationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private DemoService demoService;

    @Test
    public void index_shouldBeSuccessful() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/home").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

but I'm getting

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
```

Unlike most people posting this error, **I don't want to use JPA** for this. Am I trying to use `@WebMvcTest` incorrectly? How can I track down the Spring magic that's inviting JPA to this party?

Comment: Hi @Brad, did you find the solution? I'm in totally same situation.

Comment: @Artegon not really; I played around with various things and eventually got past it, but don't have a clear understanding of what was wrong or what fixed it. Justin's answer looks promising though

Comment: Hi @Artegon please did you find a solution to this, I'm in the same situation too

Answer (score 17):

Remove any `@EnableJpaRepositories` or `@EntityScan` from your `SpringBootApplication` class instead do this:

```
package com.tdk;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ApplicationConfig.class })
public class TdkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TdkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And put it in a separate config class:

```
package com.tdk.config;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.tdk.repositories")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.tdk.domain")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

And here the tests:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@WebMvcTest
public class MockMvcTests {

}
```

Comment: It is weird, but it does not seem to work. I tried separating out the `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotations into a separate Configuration-class, which sits next to the Application-class. The application itself properly starts up. My test however says, that the application context failed to start up (with the error mentioned by the questioner). In my case I do want to use Jpa during the real application, but I do not want to use it in my Controller-Test.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. @WebMvcTest looks for a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication (in the same directory or higher up in your app structure if it doesn't find one). You can read how this works @ https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-mvc-tests.

If your class annotated with @SpringBootApplication also has @EntityScan /@EnableJpaRepositories this error occurs. Because you have these annotations with @SpringBootApplication and you are mocking the service ( so actually not using any JPA ). I found a workaround which may not be the prettiest, but works for me.

Place this class in your test directory ( the root ). @WebMvcTest will find this class before your actual Application class. In this class you don't have to add @EnableJpaRepositories/@EntityScan.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses = {
    xxx.service.PackageMarker.class,
    xxx.web.PackageMarker.class
})
public class Application {
}
```

And your test will look the same.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@WithMockUser
public class ControllerIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        // when(service.xxx(any(xxx.class))).thenReturn(xxx); 
        // mockMvc.perform(post("/api/xxx")...
        // some assertions
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a nice solution to an annoying conflict between MVC tests and Spring Boot.  It appears necessary to name the empty application class the same as your real application class, and place it in the same package (i.e. your example only works if the application is actually named Application).  You might want to mention this in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, you can define a custom configuration class inside your test case, including only the controller (plus its dependencies), to force Spring to use *this* context.
Please note, you'll still have access to `MockMvc` and other goodness in your test case, if it's `WebMvcTest` annotated.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DemoController.class)
public class DemoControllerIntegrationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private DemoService demoService;

    @Test
    public void index_shouldBeSuccessful() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(get("/home").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Configuration
    @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { DemoController.class })
    public static class TestConf {}
```

Comment: This seems like a great approach.  However, when I try it I get another error for an unsatisfied dependency on a different RestController in the same package.  As far as I can tell, the only relation is that they are in the same package.  If @ComponentScan is only looking at the class being tested, how is there an error from an unrelated class?

Comment: @Tim ComponentScan's basePackageClasses property implies 'all component classes in this package and all sub packages'. If your controllers share the same package, you can use include/exclude filters to refine the scope.

Comment: Alternately, instead of using @ComponentScan, you can also just use the @Configuration annotation, and then inside `TestConf` add `@Bean public DemoController demoController() { return new DemoController(); }`.  Then it will only configure that one controller.

Comment: @Tim With include/exclude approach, you'll get the _real_ bean. In test config, mostly we want to mock/override the dependencies while still targeting the _real_ class under test.

Answer (score 3):

Add `@MockBean(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.class)` to above of class `DemoControllerIntegrationTests`:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DemoController.class)
@MockBean(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.class)
public class DemoControllerIntegrationTests {
    ...
}
```

Because you have not used a database in your test, Spring throws this exception. By mocking `JpaMetamodelMappingContext` class you will bypass the needed metamodel.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone uses Spring boot and don't want to remove `@EntityScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` you can remove `@WebMvcTest` annotation from your test class and add the following instead:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class DemoControllerIntegrationTests {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    //...
}
```

and you will be able to autowire `MockMvc` and use it.