# Exception "At least one JPA metamodel must be present" thrown in Controller-Test

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test a controller class annotated with `@RestController`. I am using Spring-Boot **1.5.10**.

The application itself starts up properly, but the unit test fails. Please bear in mind, that I am currently just trying to test the controller (and mock away the service - I will be testing the services later).

Here are some of my classes:

**Application.java**

```
package com.particles.authservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ ApplicationConfiguration.class })
public class Application {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationConfiguration.java**

```
package com.particles.authservice;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.convert.threeten.Jsr310JpaConverters;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = { Application.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class })
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
}
```

**AccountController.java**

```
package com.particles.authservice.accountservice;

import ...

@RestController
public class AccountController {
    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    /**
     * This method attempts to login a user and issue a token if the login was successful.
     * <p>
     * If login fails due a login attempt with a non-existent username or an invalid password, an exception is thrown.
     * 
     * @param credentials
     *            ({@link Credentials}) credentials in a JSON-form, that can be unserialized into an object of this type
     * @param response
     *            ({@link HttpServletResponse}) response, which will be sent to the client;
     *            if the credentials were valid the response receives a JWT as an additional header
     * @return ({@link PersistableAccount}) JSON (automatically serialized from the given TO);
     *         if the request was successful, an additional header containing the freshly issued JWT is added into the response
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public PersistableAccount login(@RequestBody final Credentials credentials, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        final Optional<PersistableAccount> account = accountService.login(credentials);
        if (!account.isPresent()) {
            throw new AccountLoginFailedException(credentials);
        }
        response.setHeader("Token", jwtService.tokenForPersistableAccount(account.get()));
        return account.get();
    }
}
```

**AccountControllerTest.java**

```
package com.particles.authservice;

import static ...
import ...

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@WebMvcTest(AccountController.class)
public class AccountControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private AccountService accountServiceMock;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        final Credentials credentials = TestHelper.createCredentials();
        final Optional<PersistableAccount> account = Optional.of(TestHelper.createPersistableAccount());

        given(accountServiceMock.login(credentials))
                                                    .willReturn(account);

        mockMvc
               .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/login").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
               .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

I have reduced the **AccountController** to just one endpoint and omitted imports for brevity purposes.

The test compiles just fine, but whenever I run the test, I receive the following (nested) exception (shortened - let me know if you need the full stacktrace):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.<init>(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:26)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 40 more
```

I have checked out a lot of similar questions, but the usual ways to resolve this did not seem to work in my case. In particular I tried the following:

- Using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` (did not apply to me since I was using that dependency to begin with), managed version
- Separating application from its (JPA-related) configuration due to problems in regards to `@EnableJpaRepositories` and possibly `@EntityScan` - to no avail (following the first reply in [Getting "At least one JPA metamodel must be present" with @WebMvcTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250177/getting-at-least-one-jpa-metamodel-must-be-present-with-webmvctest/42997087), but while my application still starts just fine, the test still fails)
- I have tried using JacksonTester - in fact I just want to test the controller functionality at the moment - to no avail either (ended up needing the context)
- As far as I understand I am mocking away the actual service; so in fact I am not using any JPA Metamodels, am I?

Removing the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation solves the issue, but unfortunately it seems to break my application.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 1):

Add ContextConfiguration. The test did not see ApplicationConfiguration, hence did not see any entity.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfiguration.class})
public class AccountControllerTest { ... }
```

**Update:**

Another thing the code is missing is @SpringBootTest. Try annotating the test class with this one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Sadly this did not fix the issue. The exception thrown stays the same :(.

Comment: Thanks again! It does work now, but I wanted to **just test the "RestController"-layer**. I think I might look deeper into JacksonTester. Do you happen to know if I could test the controller alone by e.g. mocking the underlying service(s) **without** using `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: You can look into MockMvc, to test RestControllers.

Comment: I made it work using `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` annotations on the test-class. However: I am under the impression that the underlying h2db is still firing up even though I do not want this (since I am mocking away the related service-calls). Do you happen to have an idea on how to prevent the database from being fired up?

Comment: It seems that after removing `@EnableJpaRepository` my application still works as expected. However: now the tests also work with just `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` and `@WebMvcTest(AccountController.class)`. According to the console output I see no database is initialized during my controller-test (which is what I want), but it is initialized during regular application execution.